# Duda PopUp o mensaje en ejecucion de PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estimados necesito de sus conocimientos, tengo el siguiente problema
tengo el siguiente código que lee un archivo csv para realizar un cruce de información a una base de datos y poder generar otro archivo csv con el resultado de este proceso.
El problema que tengo es que necesito generar un mensaje al usuario con resultado de lo que se obtuvo, pero esto no funciona debido a que cualquier código que realice en el proceso queda en el archivo que se genera, mi dudad es se puede mostrar algún mensaje con el resultado? de ser posible me ayudan a verificar mi código

index.php

```
<form  id='form_feed_cargar' name="form_feed_cargar"  method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="file" class="fileinput btn-success" name="sel_file" id="sel_file" title="Seleccione Archivo"/>

  <button type="submit" name='submit' class="btn btn-danger">Descargar</button>

</form> 

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id='tabla_cargar' name="tabla_cargar">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th width="15%" height="43" style="text-align: center" colspan="2">Reglas del archivo</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>  
    <tr>                                                    
      <th>
          Rules:<p>1.- Archivo en formato csv separado por comas<p>2.- Archivo contiene 1 columna que corresponde al numero de telefono<p>3.- El Archivo debe tener titulo (nombre aleatorio)
      </th>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

después tengo un solo código donde realizo todo, la lectura y el cruce de la información, y la generacion del archivo resultante

Busqueda.php
´´´
$fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];

```
    $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);
    if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
    {
        //si es correcto, entonces damos permisos de lectura para subir
        $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $indx = 0;
        $numeros = array();
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
        {
            if ($indx > 0 and $data[0]<>''){
                //se guardan los datos en un arreglo para buscar en la base
                $numeros[] = $data[0];              
            }
            $indx++;
        }
        //cerramos la lectura del archivo "abrir archivo" con un "cerrar archivo"
        fclose($handle);            
        $conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $nombreusuario, $password, $db);
        if ($conexion->connect_error) {
            die("Conexión fallida: " . $conexion->connect_error);
        }else{
            //se crea tabla con nombre random para evitar que alla duplicidad de consultas
            $key = '';
            $pattern = '1234cdwxyz';
            $max = strlen($pattern)-1;
            for($i=0;$i < 5;$i++) {$key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};}
            $nombretabla="temporal_".$key;
            $nombretabla2="Noencontrados_".$key;
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$nombretabla." (
                    numero_abonado varchar(100),                        
                    inar varchar(100)                           
                    )";
            $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE ".$nombretabla2." (
                    numero_abonado varchar(100)                                                 
                    )";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($sql2); 
                    //si se crea de manera exista empezamos a recorer los numeros del arreglo obtenido del archivo ingresado
            if ($conexion->query($sql) === true) {  
                $i=0;   //valor encontrado
                $x=0;   //valor no encontrado
                //recorremos arreglo de numeros ingresados          
                foreach ($numeros as &$numero) {                            
                    //echo "$numero <br>";                              
                    $sql = "select * from parque where numero_abonado ='$numero' group by numero_abonado";                                  
                    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql); 
                    $totalFilas=0;                          
                    $totalFilas  = mysqli_num_rows($resultado); 
                    if ($totalFilas>0) {
                        $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                        //validamos que existan resultados en la consulta
                        //$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);                                                                 
                        $numero_abonado = $fila['numero_abonado'];                             
                        $inar = $fila['inar'];
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$nombretabla."( numero_abonado, inar) 
                                VALUES ('$numero_abonado','$inar')";                            
                        if ($conexion->query($sql) === true) {
                            //echo "$numero_abonado <br>";  
                            //en caso de que todo este ok aumentamos variable para la creacion del archivo de la exportacion
                            $i++;                       
                        }       
                    }else{
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$nombretabla2."( numero_abonado) 
                                VALUES ('$numero')";                            
                        if ($conexion->query($sql) === true) {
                            //echo "$numero_abonado <br>";  
                            //en caso de que todo este ok aumentamos variable para la creacion del archivo de la exportacion
                        $x++;               
                        }       
                    }               
                }
                if ($x>0) {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript>alert("Registros encontrados: y no encontrados");</script>"';
                }
                //validamos que se allan ENCONTRADO registros y asi porder generar el archivo excel
                if ($i>0) {
                    $sql = "select * from ".$nombretabla;
                    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql); 
                    // NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO Y CHARSET
                    header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="parque.csv"');
                    // SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
                    $salida=fopen('php://output', 'w');
                    // ENCABEZADOS
                    fputcsv($salida, array('numero_abonado',  'inar'));
                    $reporteCsv=$conexion->query("select * from ".$nombretabla);
                    while($filaR= $reporteCsv->fetch_assoc())
                            fputcsv($salida, array($filaR['numero_abonado'],                                                                        
                                    $filaR['inar'])
                            );
                    fclose($salida);
                    //en caso de que tdoo salga bien                                    
                    $sql = "DROP TABLE ".$nombretabla;      
                    if($conexion->query($sql) === true){    

                    }
                    if($x>0){
                        $sql = "select * from ".$nombretabla2;
                        $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);                                
                        // NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO Y CHARSET
                        header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="RegistrosNoEncontrados.csv"');
                        // SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
                        $salida2=fopen('php://output', 'w');
                        // ENCABEZADOS
                        fputcsv($salida2, array('numero_abonado'));
                        $reporteCsv2=$conexion->query("select * from ".$nombretabla2);
                        while($filaR2= $reporteCsv2->fetch_assoc())
                                fputcsv($salida2, array($filaR2['numero_abonado'])                                          
                                );
                        fclose($salida2);
                        //en caso de que tdoo salga bien                                    
                        $sql = "DROP TABLE ".$nombretabla2;     
                        if($conexion->query($sql) === true){    

                        }
                    }                                                                                       
                }else{
                    if($x>0){
                        $sql = "select * from ".$nombretabla2;
                        $resultado = $conexion->query($sql); 
                        $i = 2;
                        // NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO Y CHARSET
                        header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="RegistrosNoEncontrados.csv"');
                        // SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
                        $salida2=fopen('php://output', 'w');
                        // ENCABEZADOS
                        fputcsv($salida2, array('numero_abonado'));
                        $reporteCsv2=$conexion->query("select * from ".$nombretabla2);
                        while($filaR2= $reporteCsv2->fetch_assoc())
                                fputcsv($salida2, array($filaR2['numero_abonado'])                                          
                                );
                        fclose($salida2);
                        //en caso de que tdoo salga bien                                    
                        $sql = "DROP TABLE ".$nombretabla2;     
                        if($conexion->query($sql) === true){    

                        }
                    }
                    $sql = "DROP TABLE ".$nombretabla2;
                    if($conexion->query($sql) === true){    

                    }
                    //no se encontraron registros en la base
                    $sql = "DROP TABLE ".$nombretabla;   //borro la base temporal
                    if($conexion->query($sql) === true){                                        
                        }

                }                   
            }else{
                die("Error al crear tabla temporal: " . $conexion->error);                  
            }           
        }

    }else{
        //si aparece esto es posible que el archivo no tenga el formato adecuado, inclusive cuando es cvs, revisarlo para             
        //ver si esta separado por " , "        
        ?>
            <script languaje="javascript">
                alert("Debe Selecionar un archivo!!!");
                location.href = "ayuda_parke.php";
            </script>
        <?php
    }
```

el problema es que todo el código que pueda colocar entre el proceso de lectura del archivo y generación del archivo del cruce no se ejecuta y queda en el archivo que estoy generando.
Debo separar todo el código? hacer uno para lectura y después de que se lean los datos podría crear unas tablas y después con otro botón que active leer el resultado?

Comment: En el último if estás usando `$x`, ¿dónde defines esa variable? ¿No debería ser `$indx`?

Comment: $x es una variable que voy incrementando en caso de que la búsqueda a la base de datos no me arroje algún match, no quise colocar todo el código donde realizo la búsqueda y carga de datos

Comment: Y yo me pregunto porqué omites el código que pudiera ser el origen del problema.

Comment: agregue el código, la idea era poder crear los dos archivos al mismo tiempo, si el código esta desordenado te pido disculpas llevo poco tiempo programando en php y había harto código que he tenido que ir acomodando para que no se pierda la estructura del sitio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes combinar salida HTML y descarga de archivo; tampoco puedes descargar más de un archivo al mismo tiempo, ¿Por qué?

Cuando inicias una salida (HTML, o cualquier caracter: espacio(s), salto(s) de línea, etc.) PHP envía encabezados al navegador para decirle que el contenido que va a recibir es código HTML y debe tratar de renderizarlo.

Cuando quieres que un archivo se descargue, envías los encabezados adecuados (como estás haciendo ahora) y el navegador "sabrá" que todo lo que viene después corresponde a ese archivo.

Una vez que el navegador recibe los encabezados, digamos que se pone en "modo HTML" o en "modo archivo", dependiendo de lo que hayas enviado e ignorará cualquier encabezado posterior, porque no puede intercalar entre "modos", trabajando siempre con una sola salida: HTML o archivo en tu caso.

¿Qué opción tienes?

Genera los archivos y guárdalos en disco. Cuando el proceso finalice, muestra los mensajes que sean necesario y enlaces para descarga de los archivos.

Pensándolo bien, si quieres hacer un solo paso (descarga de archivos) podrías crear un ZIP con ambos archivos y, de hecho, podrías mostrar contenido HTML, incluyendo una etiqueta `META REFRESH` para descarga del archivo comprimido.

Comment: Triby muchas gracias por tu explicación del porque no puedo generar los dos, voy a ver la forma de generar los archivos en el server para mostrar los enlaces de descarga que correspondan

Comment: una pregunta triby para guardar los archivos en el server deberia cambiar $salida2=fopen('php://output', 'w'); en ambos casos o no? y quitar el tema de los header, agradeceria tu ayuda

Comment: @JorgeValenzuela, sí, es correcto; puedes mantener la variable `$salida2`, pero cambia `php://output` por ruta y nombre de archivo donde guardarás los datos.

Comment: te pasaste, gracias por tu ayuda, ahora haré el zip para que se descarguen ambos archivos en caso de ser necesario.